# IOS: hide keyboard on touch UITableView

Tags: ios, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer

I am new in iOS development. I want to hide the keyboard when tapping outside of a UITextView.
My TextView is in a cell from an UITableView. The problem is that I have a Toolbar at the top and my buttons doesn't react anymore. I implemented the method "shouldReceiveTouch" but my test is not correct i think. Any ideas? Thank you and sorry for my bad english..

**In my ViewDidLoad:**

```
tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                               initWithTarget:self
                               action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
tap.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

note: tap is an UITapGestureRecognizer property.

**Implemented methods:**

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
   shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIBarButtonItem class]]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

-(void)dismissKeyboard {
    [tview resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Have you set the tview delegate to your view controller? tview.delegate = self and make sure to implement the UITextViewDelegate in the header file

Comment: Lookup touchesBegan method

Answer (score 1):

UIBarButtonItem is not a subclass of UIView, hence the shouldReceiveTouch still return YES.

Try to exclude the whole UIToolbar or just add the tap gesture recognizer in the UITableViewCell when you initialize the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
   shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIToolbar class]]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use didScroll method of UIScrollView delegate to resign keyboard.TableView is also subclass of UIScrollView so it should work.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
     [tview resignFirstResponder];
}
```

or use this one

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
  [tview resignFirstResponder];
}
```

If you still want to use gesture then add gesture to UIView or self.view or superView of tableView
instead of adding it to tableView

Try following code :----

**Keep you code as it is and add this method**

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     [tview resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: This works but that is not what I want. With your solution the user must scroll and not just tap.

Comment: I think gesture should not work on UIScrollView or its subclass

Comment: I try your solution with the touchesBegan, but still doesn't work. It just never enter into this method. I used the same code than in my post + your touchesBegan method but I still can't use the button from the ToolBar. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: then you should prefer scrollViewWillBeginDraggin. No other option left

Answer (score 0):

You should add your gesture to table view.

```
 tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    tap.delegate = self;
    [tblView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Comment: y you are using gestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer method

Comment: My UIToolBar is part of the UITableView i think. This is way it dosen't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

in viewDidLoad set self.view.userInteractionEnabled = yes;

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

if ([touch view] == tview) {

    [tview resignFirstResponder];

}

}
```